# Magento - Is it possible to add a menu item in the Admin section, but only on some Magento version?

Tags: magento, menu, admin

I developed a Magento extension which implements several functionalities. Almost all of them work perfectly in versions from 1.4 to 1.7, except for one. That one is an extra form, which is nice to have, but not vital for the rest of the module to work.
To open that form, a menu entry is added to the Admin menu. In versions 1.5 and 1.4, opening such window results in an error message, due to the lack of some classes introduced in version 1.6.

I'm therefore wondering if it would be possible **not** to add the menu entry to the Admin menu if Magento version is < 1.6. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any nice event to achieve this.

You can try to observe `adminhtml_init_system_config` and check wether the menu is in the `$config`. If it is, you can add or delete things.

Alternative is to rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` or `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config`

But rewriting is a bit overkill if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I think that, for the moment, I'll just add a warning in the plugin page in the Marketplace and, if Users will try to use that page, show it instead of the page itself. I'm aware that it's not 100% "cool", but, after all, that's a secondary feature. Then, if enough clients will show interest in having it for Magento 1.5, I can work on it. :)